# PDE - The minimal damping factor of 1/10000 has been reached, NDSolveValue: PDESolve could not find a solution

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method

I am trying to find a solution to a system of partial differential equations using Mathematica.

$$    
    \begin{align}
        D_{e}\frac{\partial^{2}C_{A}}{\partial r^{2}}+\frac{D_{e}}{r}\frac{\partial C_{A}}{\partial r}+D_{e}\frac{\partial^{2}C_{A}}{\partial z^{2}}-U_{z}\frac{\partial C_{A}}{\partial z}+r_{A} &= 0 \\
    k_{e}\frac{\partial^{2}T}{\partial z^{2}}+\frac{k_{e}}{r}\frac{\partial }{\partial r}\left(r\frac{\partial T}{\partial r}\right)+\Delta H_{r}^{\circ}r_{A}-U_{z}C_{pm}\frac{\partial T}{\partial z}&=0
    \end{align}
$$

Subject to the following boundary conditions

$$    
    \begin{equation}
    \text{At } r=0,~\text{then } \frac{\partial C_{A}}{\partial r}=0~\text{and } \frac{\partial T}{\partial r} = 0 \\
    \text{At } r=R,~\text{then } \frac{\partial C_{A}}{\partial r}=0~\text{and } \frac{\partial T}{\partial r} = \frac{U}{k_{e}}(T_{a0}-T) \\
    \text{At } z=0,~\text{then } C_{A}=C_{A0}~\text{and } T=T_{0}
    \end{equation}
$$

In fact, there is a tutorial in the wolfram documentation center about how to solve this [problem](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/PDEModels/tutorial/Multiphysics/ModelCollection/TubularReactor.html). Consider the following example

```
(*Data*)

    R=0.1;
    L=1.0;
    k0=1.28/3600;
    CA0=1587.4;
    Cp0=3874.5;
    Ea=75362.0;
    d=1.0*10^-9;
    s=0.559;
    U=1300.0;
    T0=312.0;
    Ta0=273.0;
    Hr0=-84666.0;
    v0=6.2999*10^-5;
    Ac=Pi*R^2;
    u0=v0/Ac;
    uz=2*u0*(1-(r/R)^2);
    Rg=8.314;
    R1=1.0*10^-6;
    k=k0*Exp[-(Ea/Rg)*(1/T[r,z]-1/300)];
    rA=-k*CA[r,z];

(*PDE's*)

    eq1=(d*D[CA[r,z],r,r] + (d/r)*D[CA[r,z],r] + d*D[CA[r,z],z,z] - uz*D[CA[r,z],z] + rA);
    eq2=(s*D[T[r,z],z,z] + (s/r)*D[r*D[T[r,z],r],r] + Hr0*rA - uz*Cp0*D[T[r,z],z]);
    c1=NeumannValue[0,r==R1||r==R];
    c2=NeumannValue[(U/s)*(Ta0-T[r,z]),r==R];
    c3=DirichletCondition[CA[r,z]==CA0,z==0];
    c4=DirichletCondition[T[r,z]==T0,z==0]; 

(*Solving for CA and T*)

    pde = {eq1==c1,eq2==c2,c3,c4};
    NDSolveValue[pde,{CA,T}, {r,R1,R},{z,0,L},"InitialSeeding"->{CA[r,z]==CA0,T[r,z]==Ta0}]
```

However, when I try to find the numerical solution, NDSolveValue throws the following error message:

```
*FindRoot: The minimal damping factor of 1/10000 has been reached. NDSolveValue: PDESolve could not find a solution.*
```

On the other hand, I have followed the exact steps in the wolfram documentation center tutorial, but I still end up getting the same error message.

Comment: What OS and Mathematica version do you have?

Comment: I have Mathematica 13.2, although I get the same error in 12.2. The above in both the macOS and Linux version.

Comment: I see the message from your example, but the example from the ref page runs cleanly on Linux. If your notebook is a copy of that page then you have most likely made a mistake when you copied it. Or is your example different from the ref page? It's not quite clear to me what you are asking.